# How can I take user input and see if it matches a key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, input

I have a dictionary of names `{first : last}`, and I am looking to take in a user input to cross reference the keys in that dictionary, while using an if/else statement. At one point it was working as intended but after running it multiple times to test something further down in the code, it randomly stopped working, despite it being in a separate function.

Code:

```
def find_tech():
  t2techs = {'FirstName1': 'LastName1', 'FirstName2': 'LastName2'}

  t1techs = {
  'FirstName3': 'LastName3',
  'FirstName4': 'LastName4',
  'FirstName5': 'LastName5',
  'FirstName6': 'LastName6',
  'FirstName7': 'LastName7',
  'FirstName8': 'LastName8'
  }
  all_techs = t2techs.copy()
  all_techs.update(t1techs)
  
  print('Who was your support tech today? \n')
  for key, value in all_techs.items():
    print(key)

  x = input('\nTech: ')
  if x is key in all_techs.keys():
    print('Thanks.\n')
  else:
    print('Invalid selection \n') + find_tech()

find_tech()
```

Note: `FirstName#` and `LastName#` are string values, actual names are hidden for confidentiality.

All inputs loop the else statement.

Comment: if `x in all_techs` is enough for checking if x is a key. If you dont need the value in the other for loop `for key in all_techs.keys()` is enough (theoretically you could also drop the .key())

Comment: You were a bit unlucky, key was used as a variable above - so it was a valid variable name. `x is key` was a statement that evaluated to True/False then and didn`t raise a NameError.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `if x is key in all_techs.keys():`

Instead use `if x in all_techs:`